# add new object to json-server; AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-resource, json-server

I have an angular app that supposed to work with json-server for retrieving data and adding new data (users feedback). so I have json database with some arrays and one of them is `"feedbacks":[]` which is currently empty. on PUT method I get:

`PUT /feedbacks 404` from server and this is chrome console `PUT http://localhost:3000/feedbacks 404 (Not Found)`.

this is my service:

```
angular.module('myApp')
        .constant("baseURL", "http://localhost:3000/")
.service('feedbackService',['$resource','baseURL',function($resource,baseURL){
      this.getFeedback=function(){
        return $resource(baseURL+"feedbacks/:date",null,{
          'update':{
            method:'PUT'
          }
        });
      };
    }]);
```

this is the controller:

```
    // contactus.html controllers
.controller('ContactController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.feedback = {firstName: "",lastName: "",email: "",date: ""};
        }])
        // Feedback form controller
        .controller('FeedbackController', ['$scope', 'feedbackService', function($scope, feedbackService) {
            $scope.feedbacks = feedbackService.getFeedback().query(function(response) {
                $scope.feedbacks = response;
            });
            $scope.sendFeedback = function() {
                    $scope.feedback.date = new Date().toISOString();
                    $scope.feedbacks.push($scope.feedback);
                    feedbackService.getFeedback().update($scope.feedbacks);
                    $scope.feedbackForm.$setPristine();
                    $scope.feedback = {firstName: "",lastName: "",email: "", date:""};
            };
        }])
```

`getFeedbacks()` method works and server send 200, but for PUT I receive 404.

Comment: You have to check for your service layer. Nothing to do here in front end.

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi I am new to this, what should I check in service Layer?

Comment: check the put method working in server part

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi yes PUT method works, cause I have another controller for commenting and there PUT works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I solved it :)) a very silly mistake. there was no need for push and then update as I wanted to create new object inside the array.

```
$scope.feedback.date = new Date().toISOString();
feedbackService.getFeedback().save($scope.feedback);
```

and also I changed the service to:

```
return $resource(baseURL+"feedbacks/:id",null,{
```

to have auto incremental id for each object